# Javascript - how to get variable value from another function in different function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get variable d value from function b in function e, but the result not value from function b. The result just from variable outside the function b.

```
var d = "maybe";
var a = 1;

function b() {
    if (a == 1) {
        var d = "yes";
    } else {
        var d = "no";
    }
}
b();

function e() {
console.log(d); //output maybe
}
e();
```

How do I get the result to be the value from function b, or equal to "yes"?

Comment: Being a newbie is fine. Not researching is a sin.

Comment: Inside your function b delete the var for parameter d, it should work. Do some search on the global and local variables.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan. I really don't know if the keyword is scope of variable, but again thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to use the `var` keyword when you define the variable. If you want to change the variable afterwords, don't use `var`. If you do you'll actually be making a new variable inside the function. So the code you want is:

```
var d = "maybe";
var a = 1;

function b() {
    if (a == 1) {
        d = "yes";
    } else {
        d = "no";
    }
}
b();

function e() {
    console.log(d); // now it outputs yes
}
e();
```

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. 
Thank you very much..